How to access dropdown panel click event in CKEditor5?
I want to listen to the font list toolbar dropdown click event in CKEditor5. I am not able to find how to access the fonts list dropdown component of CKEditor5. How does one register for this event?
I went through lot of answers here on stackoverflow, but they are mostly for custom dropdown plugins created. I want to register a listener for the in-built fonts list dropdown plugin.
Any pointers would help.
TIA.
